# SQL Schema Creation (Brainstorming help?)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-schema

I am trying to figure out the best organization for the tables/fields of my SQL database.

Let me explain the functionality of the product. My organization has scheduled volunteer services 5 days a week at different times each day. I am making a program to allow a user to login, select days/times for volunteering, and sign up to volunteer for the selected times. The user will select the amount of volunteers they are bringing with them and the amount of cars they are bringing. There is a minimum of 2 cars and 3 people per each volunteer outing. The users have to be on an approved list.

I have no clue how to best organize all of this data. I cannot add fields to a user table for car # and amount of volunteers they are bringing because this could change depending what day they are signing up for.

My current idea (bad):

VolunteerOutings Table

```
- DateTime time
- Array of userIds (will be used to access CarVolunteerInfo)
```

user Table

```
- int userId
- varchar email
- varchar pass
```

CarVolunteerInfo Table

```
- DateTime time
- int userId
- int car #
- int volunteer #
```

Multiple people can sign up for one outing, and I want to be able to see who is signed up for each outing and what they are bringing. Also I want to be able to run reports to see all past and future outings they are signed up for.

I am sorry if this question is too vague or theoretical. I am happy to improve my question at your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three rules of thumb:

1. Break it down into simple elements
2. Check against sample workflows from the user's point of view
3. Make sure you don't duplicate information

So - we clearly have things like: user, outing, vehicle and perhaps project (for something ongoing with multiple outings). Then, you will have linking tables (attendees = outing, user etc).

Then you get into details. These vehicles - is one user responsible for bringing each? How large are they? Do we need to make sure there are enough seats for the # users attending? Do we care who is going in each car?

Finally, make sure you aren't duplicating information. Dave's name can be looked up from his user-id, and the number of seats in his car probably won't change from outing to outing (until he changes cars... whoops - add that to the workflow).

Your sample looks OK for a first draft, just expect to go through the process a few times refining it. Oh - if possible have some scripts to:

1. Generate table definitions
2. Add some test data
3. Run basic tests against the database

That will help lots. Something like [pgtap](http://pgtap.org/) can help with the testing if you are using PostgreSQL.